SSH2-SFTP-client module won't import
I am trying to import and use the ssh2-sftp-client package for my React/Electron project, but any time I add the import to a file, I get a massive wall of module errors. They are all either
"Can't resolve "xxxx" in "C:\users\username\project\node_modules\ssh2\lib""
or
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'xxxx' in 'C:\user\username\project\node_modules\ssh2\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

These missing packages include stream, net, path, crypto, fs, child_process, dns, http, https, tls, and a few more.
Versions:
React - 18.3.1,
Node - 20.15.1,
Electron - 31.2.0
I have ssh2 and ssh2-sftp-client installed in my project, and they are in my package.json. I have also tried the recommended changes to my webpack.config.js file, where I add the fallback for each of these module errors, and I've done npm -ci multiple times.
My import looks like this (but I have also tried different imports from the same package):
import { Client } from "ssh2-sftp-client"
I can't shake the feeling that I'm missing something simple in my project; like there's a specific package or config missing that would fix all of this.
